# What hosted continuous integration offerings exist supporting macOS UI tests with Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, testing, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a hosting provider (like [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/)) which supports UI tests for macOS applications written in Swift (like [these](https://github.com/powderhouse/Atlas/blob/master/AtlasAppUITests/AtlasUITestCase.swift)).  CircleCI does not, and there are not plans to with 2.0.

I know I could find a hosted Mac provider (like [MacStadium](https://www.macstadium.com/)) and set up XCode Server bots or similar for CI, or set up my own, but I'm hoping for something a bit more batteries-included.

Thanks!